# How to enable Tap to click on MATE desktop (Debian 8.7 powerpc)

Tags: debian, touchpad, mate-desktop, powerpc

Using advice from this forum, I got tap to click working in LXDE on my Powerbook G4 running Debian 8.7. I have since been experimenting with the MATE desktop, how do I get tap to click working in MATE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to do that under LXDE? It should be no different from that; after all, the technologies at base are the same.

Since LXDE has no specific control panel or anything of the sorts, I suspect you add some command to some startup file? That will work with mate desktop, too. If you can't find any such startup file, you can always use your `~/.Xsession` to deal with that. In that file, you'd first have to place the command(s) that configure your touchpad, and after that you'd place the correct command to start mate desktop.

This solution will work for whatever graphical environment you're using, not just mate.

Comment: To get it working in LXDE, I created a file                                          /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf and added the necessary commands. I can confirm that this doesn't affect the Mate desktop as I am using it now and I cannot tap to click or use two-fingered scrolling. Both features now work in LXDE.

Comment: But not when I enable the Mate desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps. It worked for me. My notebook is SAMSUMG NP270E5G-KDRBR, Core i5, Debian 9 with MATE.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

After that:

- Go to: System - Preferences - Hardware - Mouse
- Click in the tab Touchpad
- Check the option: enable mouse clicks with touchpad
- Reboot

Answer (score 0):

If synaptics isn't working for you, check to see if you have a non-synaptics touch pad:

```
$ egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

If you do not find a synaptics touch pad, but one from a different vendor (mine is an Elantech touchpad for example), try the following commands:

```
$ apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
$ apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-{libinput,evdev,mouse}

$ mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
$ echo 'Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
$ systemctl restart lightdm
```

If restarting lightdm doesn't work, try rebooting your computer.

More information: https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Enable_tapping_on_touchpad

Answer (score -1):

How about "setting" of File Manager in MATE desktop?

What I did is that:

1. Open "File Manager" app from "Location" menu from panel at the top of display monitor.  The app name is "Caja" at CentOS-7.
2. Select "Edit" > "Setting" from menu.
3. Select "Action" tab.
4. Select "Single click to open item"

Comment: `Single click to open item` has nothing to do with tap to click which is a touchpad feature where you tap on it to do a left click instead of pressing the left mouse button